# Is there a way to reverse a string faster than O(n)?

Tags: java, string, performance, optimization, big-o

I have the following code which takes more than 5 seconds to run with the argument `-Xmx<1024M>`.

I am aware that the `for` loop takes `O(q)` time, as well as the `reverse()` and `toString()` take `O(n)` time each.

Is there a way to reverse the string in less than `O(n)` time? Or is something else slowing the code down? Any help would be welcome!

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "a";
    String qa = "200000";
    int q = Integer.parseInt(qa);
    String[] t = new String[q];
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
      if(i%2==0) {t[i] = "2 1 x";}
      if(i%2==1) {t[i] = "1";}
      if(t[i].toCharArray()[0] == '1') {
        StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(s).reverse();
        s = rev.toString();
      } else {
        char letter = t[i].toCharArray()[4];
        if(t[i].toCharArray()[2] == '1') {
          s = letter + s;
        } else {
          s = s + letter;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible since it takes n/2 swaps

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: is the goal just to reverse a string? There's a much easier way.

Comment: In order to reverse something you have to actively touch all elements to change their position (assuming we do not talk about implicit reversal). By design, this is bound by `Omega(n)`. It is impossible to come up with anything faster (in terms of asymptotic complexity).

Comment: This doesn't even print anything.  Nor is it explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you talk about complexity but then you ask about making your code faster. Complexity and actual real speed do not have that much in common. So what exactly are you asking? Making your code faster or improving the complexity? Also, do you have a proper benchmark setup to measure the speed of your code, e.g. with jmh?

Comment: This is a good question, however it needs an update, so please do it. If you want to make the code faster and below 5 seconds, ask for the optimization of Java code and the algorithm itself. If your question is only about achieving the better O(n), don't speak about the time complexity then.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what is it supposed to do (I have no idea), I found the following problems:

- Multiple instantinations of `StringBuilder` in each iteration.
- String concatenation using `+` operator.
- Repetitive usage of `Sring::toCharArray` (see the 2nd solution)

You will achieve a faster result using directly only one instance of `StringBuilder`:

```
String s = "a";
String qa = "200000";
int q = Integer.parseInt(qa);
String[] t = new String[q];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);       // Instantiate before the loop
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    if(i%2==0) {t[i] = "2 1 x";}
    if(i%2==1) {t[i] = "1";}
    if(t[i].toCharArray()[0] == '1') {
        sb.reverse();                          // all you did here is just reversing 's'
    } else {
        char letter = t[i].toCharArray()[4];
        if(t[i].toCharArray()[2] == '1') {
            sb.insert(0, letter);              // prepend a letter
        } else {
            sb.append(letter);                 // append a letter
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is that you multiple times define a String such as `t[i] = "2 1 x";` and then you compare with `t[i].toCharArray()[0]`. Pre-definig these immutable values and using `char[][]` should help too:

```
String s = "a";
String qa = "200000";
int q = Integer.parseInt(qa);
char[][] t = new char[q][];                    // char[][] instead of String[]
char[] char21x = new char[]{'2', '1', 'x'};    // predefined array
char[] char1 = new char[]{'1'};                // another predefined array
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);       // Instantiate before the loop
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    if(i%2==0) {t[i] = char21x;}     // first reuse
    if(i%2==1) {t[i] = char1;}       // second reuse
    if(t[i][0] == '1') {             // instead of String::toCharArray, mind the indices
        sb.reverse();                // all you did here is just reversing 's'
    } else {
        char letter = t[i][2];       // instead of String::toCharArray, mind the indices
        if(t[i][1] == '1') {
            sb.insert(0, letter);    // prepend a letter
        } else {
            sb.append(letter);       // append a letter
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I have tested the solution with the simplest way possible using a difference of `System.currentTimeMillis()` on my laptop:

- Original solution: `7.658`, `6.899` and `7.046` seconds
- 2nd solution: `3.288`, `3.691` and `3.158` seconds
- 3rd solution: `2.717`, `2.966` and `2.717` seconds

**Conclusion:** I see no way to improve the algorithm itself in terms of the computation complexity, however, using the correct ways to treat Strings helps to reduce the time complexity 2-3 times (in my case).

**General advice**: What you can instantiate and define before the loop, do it before the loop.

Comment: On my laptop, it takes about 2 seconds in comparison to 6 seconds for the original solution

Comment: The OP is also converting to a String and then feeding back into StringBuilder.

Comment: @Zabuza: Yeah, I have been thinking about that, but I haven't been doing it ever before. Seems I have to fill the gap in my knowledge :D

Comment: @WJS: If you mean `t[i].toCharArray()`-alike calls, I have included it in my answer already.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to reverse the string in less than O(n) time? Or is something else slowing the code down?

No there is no way to reverse a string in less than O(n) time: A program that produces an output of size n necessarily takes o(n) time at the minimum.

Your code has lots of unnecessary operations that slow the program down. The program produces 50000 letters x, followed by one letter a, followed by another 50000 letters x. Here is a much faster (and easier to understand) implementation of the same program.

```
class Faster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String hundredXs = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            System.out.print(hundredXs);

        System.out.print("a");

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            System.out.print(hundredXs);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```